# Pandas - Check If First Character Is Special Character

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a sample dataframe df.

I would like to know if there is a way to return all values that begin w a special character.

I currently have it to only return values with the '@' sign, but would like all special characters. Or at least how to list multiple options using regex

```
Fruits

Apple
-Orange
$Pear
Cherry
@Grape
```

```
df.str.contains(r'^\[@]')]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you define special character as anything which is not alphanumeric, we can try:

```py
df[df["Fruits"].str.contains(r'^[^A-Za-z0-9]')]
```

Comment: looks like the ^ sign inside the bracket acts as a "not" operator. Does this mean ^ acts as first character as well as "not"?

Comment: @VoidS `^` inside a character class `[^...]` means _not_ the characters inside brackets.

Comment: @wwnde No, that's the long way.  You _could_ use `str.contains(r'^[\W_]')`

Answer (score 1):

DataFrame

```
Fruits
0   Apple
1   -Orange
2   $Pear
3   Cherry
4   @Grape
5   _Grape
```

Check if the first character is alphanumeric

```
df['Fruits'].str.contains('^\_|[^\w]')
```

you can then filter if needed

```
df[df['Fruits'].str.contains('^\_|[^\w]')]
```

Outcome

```
Fruits
1  -Orange
2    $Pear
4   @Grape
5   _Grape
```

Comment: Note that `\w` includes underscore `_`.  It is not clear whether the OP wants to treat underscore as a special character.

Comment: This is good, this seems to pull the alpanumeric. I was interested in special characters being pulled

Comment: Sorry didnt read it properly, this is the much neater way to do it